# nltk ChartParser doesnot show any result

Tags: nltk

I am trying to recreate the example shown first in (http://www.nltk.org/book/ch08.html), but with different sentence and grammar structure.
However, when I run the following program, I cannot see any result produced by `parser.parse()`. No error, no anything.

What am I missing here?

```
from nltk import pos_tag, word_tokenize, CFG
import nltk

grammar = nltk.CFG.fromstring("""
DT -> 'Any' | 'any'
DT -> 'the'
JJ -> 'habitable'
NNS -> 'areas' | 'Scientists'
NN -> 'border' | 'planet' | 'region'
IN -> 'in' | 'that' | 'on'
VPB -> 'are' | 'think'
S -> NP VP
NP -> NP PP
NP -> DT NG
NP -> NNS
NG -> JJ NG
NG -> NN
NG -> NNS
NG -> NN NN
VP -> VBP PP
PP -> IN NP
""")

sent = "Scientists think that any habitable areas on the planet are in the border region".split()
parser = nltk.ChartParser(grammar)
for tree in parser.parse(sent):
    print(tree)
```

Comment: Your grammar cannot embed a sentence in a PP. Your sentence is unparseable.

Comment: `parser.parse(sent)` should return a list of sentences that are parse-able. In the case that no sentence is yielded from your grammar, then it returns and empty list. To debug your grammar, first try to humanly write out the expected parse of your example sentence and then work through the grammar manually to see whether a parse is possible =)